# What's special about mixlib-shellout in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

The [Chef style guide](https://docs.chef.io/ruby.html#) rather forcefully states:

> Always use `mixlib-shellout` to shell out. Never use backticks, `Process.spawn`, `popen4`, or anything else!

Unfortunately, it doesn't explain *why* those alternatives are deprecated. Is there some hidden danger here (in the same vein as "never use `gets()`"), or does `mixlib-shellout` just have a better feature set / interface / etc?

Comment: Better feature, env variables management, better way to capture output, better handling of return codes. The list is quite long, + the fact it handle running commands under unix or windows cleanly (fork under unix, Win32 API under windows) which others don't. (This sounds an Off Topic question to me, hence the clues in comment and not as an answer). Edit: I more or less said the same as the [Readme](https://github.com/chef/mixlib-shellout)

Comment: @Tensibal Maybe this would be better for Server Fault, but thanks for your help. You exceeded the `mixlib-shellout` readme by sort-of answering my "hidden danger or just incrementally better?" question.